# Change the text on a Google Slide using animation

Tags: google-slides

I need a slide which shows a horizontal arrow for time and communicate what is happening at each event on that timeline.  Instead of showing what is happening for all events at once, I wish to use animation to just display what is happening individually for each event at a time.

Initially, I will show a marker on the arrow time-line at the beginning and will have some text which will describe what is happening for that time.  Upon clicking, the next marker will be displayed after the initial one and the previous text will be replaced with the new appropriate text.  And so on...

I understand how to add additional markers on the timeline, however, not how to replace the text.

Is it possible to do so, and if so, how?